# Mixing current in Gilbert cell

Tags: transistors, modulation, gilbert-cell

I'm currently breaking my head over this Gilbert cell:
[image: schematic]

I understand the workings of this circuit, that is not the issue I'm having.
What I do not understand is, when looking at the current waveforms:

[image]

How do you get this resulting output? I understand it all the way to where the red arrows are drawn, but not how you get this result from combining those 2, where is the DC current offset?

Comment: EE&O, To be "complete", for newbies, "something" written is missing at the bottom left of your pictures ... *ic1*+ic3 ... and *ic1*+ic3-ic2-ic4 to be complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *How do you get this resulting output? I understand it all the way to
> where the red arrows are drawn, but not how you get this result from
> combining those 2,*

A - B is the special thing here. Signal A minus signal B.

The circuit produces an **AC part of A** that is \$\color{red}{\text{antiphase}}\$ (negative in polarity) to the **AC part of B** so, if those AC parts each have an magnitude of (say) "1", when we do "A - B", we get an AC output of "2". In other words \$A_{AC} - B_{AC} = \color{blue}{1 - (- 1)} = \color{orange}{1+1 = 2}\$.

But, the DC parts of A and B are near-enough identical hence, when we do A - B we get near-zero DC output.

> *where is the DC current offset?*

It is now zero due to subtraction i.e. A minus B.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am honestly ashamed i did not think of something so simple as basic math. This cleared it up a whole lot for me, thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

EE&O. For information, an interesting "specification" of the Gilbert cell to be pointed out is the fact that one can get rid of the inherent "[distortion](http://article.sapub.org/pdf/10.5923.j.eee.20140403.02.pdf)" of the "simpler" system.

Here is explained by a picture: "distortion" about current through R1 and R2.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I'm currently not going in-depth on designing mixers, but it's interesting to read and (try to) understand!